# Prevent a Service / Activity been killed when closing the application

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

it is some days I'm trying to figure it out how to work out with this.

I have an Android application that is actually composed by a simple WebView and a button to start/stop a service. The service starts a task that (each 60 seconds) checks if there are any updates (calling an external PHP function), and in case there are, it shows a notification.

I also have a BroadcastReceiver that is called by the "*onTaskRemoved*" function of the service (I also tried to call the BroadcastReceiver from the onDestroy, but the result is the same), that restart the service when is closed.

The background service works fine while the app is open; when I close it the "*onTaskRemoved*" call the BroadcastReceiver that restarts the service and it still works for some minutes (each time it changes for how long). After some minutes the tasks checking for the updates stops working and the only message I read in the logs is something like the Activity has been killed (the last message received is *"01-09 15:03:34.593  4306  5082 I ActivityManager: Killing 13691:com.xxx.xxx/u0a262 (adj 906): DHA:SPC_empty #31*", but based on what I read in the many researches done, the service should continue to run, am I wrong?.

Here below some parts of code:

The Button Click listener that start/stop the service in the **main class**:

```
 btn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (btn.getText().equals("Start Monitoring"))
            {
                mMonitoringService = new MonitoringService(getCtx());
                mServiceIntent = new Intent(getCtx(), mMonitoringService.getClass());
                if (!isMyServiceRunning(mMonitoringService.getClass())) {
                    startService(mServiceIntent);
                }
                btn.setText("Stop Monitoring");
                ...
            }
            else
            {
                mMonitoringService = new MonitoringService(getCtx());
                if (isMyServiceRunning(mMonitoringService.getClass())) {
                    mServiceIntent = new Intent(getCtx(), mMonitoringService.getClass());
                    stopService(mServiceIntent);
                }
                btn.setText("Start Monitoring");
                ...
            }
        }
    });
```

The **Service**:

```
public class MonitoringService extends Service {

Context mContext;
private long lastCheck = System.currentTimeMillis() - 6000044;
public MonitoringService(Context applicationContext, String UsrCookie) {
    super();

    mContext = applicationContext;
    Log.i("SERVICE", "here I am!");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    if (intent != null)
        {
            Log.d("Intent","not null");
            startMyTimer(mContext);
        }
        else{
            Log.d("Intent","null");
        }


    return START_STICKY;
}



@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("EXIT", "onDestroy!");
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    Log.i("EXIT", "onTaskRemoved!");
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("com.xxx.xxx.ActivityRecognition.RestartMonitoring");
        broadcastIntent.setClass(this,MonitoringRestarterBroadcastReceiver.class);
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

    stopMyTimertask();
}

public void startMyTimer(Context inContext) {
    //set a new Timer
    myTimer = new Timer();

    //initialize the TimerTask's job
    initializeMyTimerTask(inContext);

    //schedule the timer, to wake up every 0.1 second
    myTimer.schedule(myTimerTask, 100, 100); //
}

public void initializeMyTimerTask(final Context inContext) {
    Log.i("DPCLite", "initializeMyTimerTask");
    myTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Long nowDate = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    if (((nowDate - lastCheck) / 1000) > 60 && isNetworkAvailable())
                    {
                        lastCheck = nowDate;
                        callPHPfunction(inContext);
                    }                    

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
}

public void stopMyTimertask() {
    //stop the timer, if it's not already null
    if (myTimer != null) {
        Log.i("stopMyTimertask", "STOPPED");
        myTimer.cancel();
        myTimer = null;
    }
}
```

And the **BroadcastReceiver**:

```
public class MonitoringRestarterBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(MonitoringRestarterBroadcastReceiver.class.getSimpleName(), "Service Stopped!");
    Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, MonitoringService.class);
    context.startService(newIntent);
}
}
```

Comment: An additional information:
all the above behaviour happen testing it on a Samsung A5 2017 device (having Android 7.0).
Just tested on a LG g4 (having Android 6.0) and this is not happening (the service stays alive). Any idea?

Comment: Another additional info:
Under the list of "executing services" my service seems to be still running, even after the task stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
After so much debug I found that on the samsung with Android 7.0, some time the restart of the services come with intent null, so actually the service was still running but not my task.